# Build system won't work in Sublime Text3 and Python3.7

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

On MacOS Mojave, I got Sublime text 3 and Python 3.7 /2.7/Anaconda installed.

I wanna make sure that when I run a python script like this:

```
john = "fun guy"
jenny = "nice lady"
jeremy = "geek"
users_input = str(input("Enter your best friend's name  "))
if users_input == "john":
    print("How do you know John?")
```

It actually will print the result: How do you know John? If I enter: john

My Python3.7 is in : /usr/local/bin/python3.7

Here's my build in Sublime:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "/usr/local/bin/python3.7 ${file}",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
}
```

But for some weird reason it read it from this location:

```
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Heads up, I have done

```
export PS1='$ '
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

in my `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: FYI, Sublime Text does not come with an input console, though there are packages for it. You can use SublimeREPL or Sublime Input or other plugins to support this; install via sublime package control.

Comment: Is that a `brew install`ation of Python?  

It might be reporting the antecedent of the symlink it places in `/usr/local`

Btw it is stated the official https://python.org download is superior.